# Let $a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+a_{n+1}+a_n$ Prove that $\forall N\in \mathbb Z^+ , \exists a_k$ s.t. $N\mid a_k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Define the sequence $(a_n)$ such that $$a_0=0, a_1=a_2=1\quad a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+a_{n+1}+a_n$$
Prove that $\forall N\in \mathbb Z^+ , \exists a_k$ s.t. $N|a_k$

Note that if the sequence $(a_n)$ is periodic$\mod N$ and we are given $$a_0=0\equiv 0\pmod N, \quad \forall  N \in \mathbb  Z^+$$
then we are done. Because there would be $a_k\equiv a_0\equiv 0\pmod N$.

But I have no idea how to prove that $(a_n)$ is periodic.

Comment: Hint: The map $(a,b,c) \mapsto (b,c,a+b+c)$ is a **invertible** map from the **finite** set $\mathbb{Z}_N^3$ to itself!

Comment: There are only finitely many triples of residues $\pmod N$.

Comment: Not enough to guarantee that a triplet would contain $0$ @lulu

Comment: @PNT   The recursion  runs backwards as well as forwards.  As soon as you have a duplicate, you know it must be periodic.

Comment: Can you verify my solution? @lulu

Comment: @PNT it looks ok, but a bit wordy.  once you know there is some $n,k$ such that $a_i\equiv a_{i+k}\pmod N$ for all $i≥n$ then you know that $n=0$.  After all, we can let $n_*$ denote the least such $n$ and note that, if $n_*>0$, $n_*-1$ works as well (contradicting minimality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S=\{0,1,2,...,N-1\}$ and $$A=\{(a_n, a_{n+1}, a_{n+2})\pmod N\mid n\in \mathbb N\}$$
where $(a_n, a_{n+1}, a_{n+2})\pmod N=(a_n\pmod N, a_{n+1}\pmod N, a_{n+2}\pmod N)$(Just a notation)

Note that $ A\subseteq S^3$ thus $| A| \le | S|^3=N^3< \infty= | \mathbb N| $. Hence by the piegonhole principle $\exists n\ne k$ such that
$$(a_n, a_{n+1}, a_{n+2})\pmod N=(a_k, a_{k+1}, a_{k+2})\pmod N$$
Meaning $$\cases{a_n\equiv a_k\pmod N \\ a_{n+1}\equiv a_{k+1}\pmod N\\ a_{n+2}\equiv a_{k+2}\pmod N} \implies a_{n+3}\equiv a_{k+3}\pmod N$$

Using induction it's not hard to prove $$a_{n+s}\equiv a_{k+s}, \quad \forall s\ge 0$$ but we also have $$a_n=a_{n+3}-a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}$$ Hence $$a_{n+s}\equiv a_{k+s}, \quad \forall s\in \mathbb Z$$ While we are going down we will encounter $a_0=0\equiv 0\pmod N$.

The pigeonhole always seems like magic to me.

Comment: Did you stop studying calculus O_o suprising to see you back on NT

Comment: I’m preparing for the math Olympiad in my country, Once I finish that I’ll go back to calculus. @Buraian

Comment: I also love number theory

Comment: Ohh good luck!!! :D

Comment: A small typo: the set $S$ should contain $0$.